# Azure B2C verification DisplayControl-How to hide the change button?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Based on the document,I am able to prepopulate the email address in readonly text box and send the code and verify using displaycontrol. Once the user completes the verification process, it dynamically displays "Change" button. Since it is readonly textbox, user will not be able to change the email. How can we hide the change button in displaycontrol dynamically.

Comment: Which document did you refer to to prepopulate the email address in readonly text box and send the code and verify using displaycontrol?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/display-controls . Input claims
In a display control, you can use InputClaims elements to prepopulate the value of claims to collect from the user on the page. Any InputClaimsTransformations can be defined in the self-asserted technical profile which references this display control.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have here is to use CSS as part of your custom page template to hide the "Change" button.